# How to use connection pool in jdbc with oracle database?

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using jdbc to write a java desktop application, and this application will connect to oracle database.
is the DBCP library still work ? How can I configure a datasource in java desktop application ? is there any sample code for this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about reading the documentation: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/index.html. This page ends with *There are several examples of using DBCP available.*

Comment: Interesting choice of profile name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the connection pool that is built into the Oracle driver. So you don't need to have a dependency to a 3rd party library.

For details see the JDBC Programmer's Guide it contains examples as well:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/concache.htm#CDEGABII